# Make android device to be a print server

Tags: printing

I want to connect a bluetooh printer to an android device to share it via LAN. Does anyone know that an app can make an Android device a print server, or how can I make an Android device a print server?

I need to do this, because I need to print from places where I don't have bluetooth coverage.

Comment: Is Bluetooth the only option for the printer? I don't know of any product with such limitations. If it can be connected to a network (Ethernet or WiFi) that would be a better option.

Comment: Yes, bluetooth only. https://docs.sunmi.com/en/general-function-modules/printing-service/